# Sitecore RTE inside custom form

Tags: sitecore, rte

I am writing an page inside Sitecore where users can create Sitecore items by entering some very basic information. One of the requirements is to the Sitecore RTE inside this form. The RTE should have all the command buttons available and working like linking to 'Media Library', 'Flash', 'Items', etc that come as defaults.

The control is working fine but I can't get any of the Sitecore commands to work. I get a -

> Web.config registration missing! The Telerik dialogs require a
>   HttpHandler registration in the web.config file. Please, use the
>   control's Smart Tag to add the handler automatically, or see the help
>   for more information: Controls > RadEditor > Dialogs > Introduction.

I have checked all the Telerik settings and the handler is registered. I am not sure what else I can do to resolve this.

This is very crucial for the client. Also, if there are any alternatives you can suggest would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the suggestions provided in the following help article: http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/editor/error-web-config-registration-missing-the-telerik-dialogs-require-a-httphandler-registration-in-the-web-config-file.aspx